# Python string escape

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

The content of string is like this, and it has many `"` and  many `'`, below is just a simple example, is there a way I can represent such a string as a constant string and assign to a variable without escape `"` and `'`. Just want to save some typing for escape `"` and `'` and make string more readable in code. :)

```
--pretty-print "http://foo.com" {'bbb'}
```

BTW: using Python 2.7.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: With triple-quoted strings: `"""` or `'''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use triple quotes, either single or double. You can have multiple lines in triply-quoted strings, but you don't *have* to.

```
option = """--pretty-print "http://foo.com" {'bbb'}"""
```

Comment: Thanks kindall, vote up and mark your reply as answer.